# How to enable disable button on Angular 5 forms?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 5 form with a disabled continue button, I want to enable the button when text in form is present in any control without having to list out every one.

Comment: Are you using Reactive Forms? Template Forms? Do you have a form element? Please [edit] your question to show what you've attempted to do this yourself.

Comment: [You should try first](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's a template based form, you can get the value of every input field using ViewChild ElementRef selection method. Then create a method which checks if any value of these elementRefs is not empty. If yes, then the method should return true. You can bind the button's disabled property to this method.

Comment: Yeah you can use this approch, but this is the jQuery standard. You can the same things with minor efforce, like `reactive forms` and check if the form is valid